# Migrate all products including pictures from Drupal ecommerce to magento

Tags: migration

Is there a easy way to migrate all products and categories from Drupal Commerce to Magento?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have successfully used [Cart2Cart](http://www.shopping-cart-migration.com/) to migrate products & categories from DrupalCommerce to Magento. It's easy, affordable and they offer decent support (no I'm not affiliated with them).